# Cross the "raise Exception from e" boundary to debug original exception "e"

Tags: python, pdb

I frequently find myself debugging code that looks something like this:

```py
def fn(a):
  if a != 5:
    raise ValueError('Error')


try:
  fn(a=4)
except Exception as e:
  raise RuntimeError('Caught it') from e
```

Dropping into `pdb` takes me to the `RuntimeError`, but I would like to inspect the stack trace of the original `ValueError` error. Often `fn` also runs in a separate thread making things even more complicated. Modifying the code to replace

```py
raise RuntimeError('Caught it') from e
```

with simply

```py
raise e
```

does the trick, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution to this or a command in `pdb` that allows "crossing the `from e` boundary"?